# Plotting value from matching complete pairs in rows

Tags: r, plot

I have data of drug concentrations (DV) that include a parent drug and its metabolite, coded DVID 1 and 2, respectively.  They are provided to me as separate rows, identified by study (STUDYID), subject (ID), and the time after the dose (TAD).  I have created with paste an index column that I hope is unique to each study+ID+time.  I would like to generate a data frame to plot the concentrations of the parent drug and metabolite against one another:

```
Index  Drug   Metabolite
```

Here are a few lines of data.  Note that there is not a match for the drug and metabolite at time 0.5 and 1, so I would like to exclude these unpaired records. `dcast` wants an aggregation function - I just want to match up the two concentrations from the same sample.  Also, can this be done without the concatenated Index column?

```
   STUDYID ID     TAD       DV DVID         Index
1        2  1 0.50000  0.80871    1     2SUBJ10.5
2        2  1 1.00000  2.53052    1       2SUBJ11
3        2  1 1.50000  2.64830    1     2SUBJ11.5
4        2  1 1.50000 -0.94495    2     2SUBJ11.5
5        2  1 2.01667  2.74019    1 2SUBJ12.01667
6        2  1 2.01667 -0.69375    2 2SUBJ12.01667
7        2  1 2.53333  2.91831    1 2SUBJ12.53333
8        2  1 2.53333 -0.30612    2 2SUBJ12.53333
9        2  1 3.00000  2.88926    1       2SUBJ13
10       2  1 3.00000 -0.12863    2       2SUBJ13
11       2  1 4.00000  2.78932    1       2SUBJ14
12       2  1 4.00000  0.01882    2       2SUBJ14
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first remove the rows that are unpaired, then we can plot using `ggplot`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(STUDYID, ID, TAD) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = TAD, y = DV, group = factor(DVID), color = factor(DVID)))
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you were wanting to plot the values of the pairs, then you could do something like this:

```
output <- df %>% 
  group_by(STUDYID, ID, TAD) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  mutate(row = as.integer(gl(n(), 2, n()))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "DVID", values_from = "DV") %>% 
  rename("Drug" = `1`, "Metabolite" = `2`) %>% 
  select(-row)

ggplot(output) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Drug, y = Metabolite, color = factor(TAD)))
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(STUDYID = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), TAD = c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 2.01667, 2.01667, 2.53333, 2.53333, 
3, 3, 4, 4), DV = c(0.80871, 2.53052, 2.6483, -0.94495, 2.74019, 
-0.69375, 2.91831, -0.30612, 2.88926, -0.12863, 2.78932, 0.01882
), DVID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
    Index = c("2SUBJ10.5", "2SUBJ11", "2SUBJ11.5", "2SUBJ11.5", 
    "2SUBJ12.01667", "2SUBJ12.01667", "2SUBJ12.53333", "2SUBJ12.53333", 
    "2SUBJ13", "2SUBJ13", "2SUBJ14", "2SUBJ14")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: AndrewGB, this is Brilliant!  Thank you.  Can you explain how the factor(n() >1) is working?

Comment: This works with a snippet of my 12K lines of data with drug and metabolite on different lines, but when I expand to the full dataset I get the warning: Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.   Is this because some of my values ("DV") are not unique?  I will still need to plot non-unique values.

Comment: @PHutson With `filter(n()>1)`, I am just eliminating the records that do not have any pairs. So, if there is only 1 row, then just eliminate that group. For the pivoting error, yes, you are correct. But you can just add in a line to give a row number, then it should work fine. I've added that in above with an additional `mutate` statement.

Comment: the additional mutate line does allow the filter to proceed, but I am left with the Drug and Metabolite in different lines, and now as characters because of the introduced NAs:    STUDYID    ID     TAD  DOSE   row Drug   Metabolite
    <int> <int>    <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>        <chr> 
1       2     1      1.5     32     1 14.13        NA    
2       2     1      1.5     32     2 NA           0.3887

Comment: @PHutson Alright, try it again now. I altered the `mutate` statement, so that if another row has the same value as another row in the same group, then we just create an additional group, so that it is able to be unique, which allows for it to pivot properly. Hopefully that solves the issue!

Comment: No joy.  I get the error message Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `row`.
i `row = as.integer(gl(n), 2, n())`.
x argument must be coercible to non-negative integer

Comment: Using a bigger hammer, I created a new column with a unique identifier ("Index" in original post).  I then used your code to remove the unmatched concentrations, and then used lag to look for the previous instance of the unique Index, since sample times, ID, TAD were all not unique through the entire data set. It generated NAs that I removed to yield a data.table that I could plot  It works, but the need to create the Index column is cludgy.  I figure there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want to `dcast`, you could simply `plot` the data directly.

```
plot(DV ~ TAD, df1, type='n', main='My Plot')  ## initialize
lines(DV ~ TAD, df1[df1$DVID == 1, ], type='b', pch=16, col=2)
lines(DV ~ TAD, df1[df1$DVID == 2, ], type='b', pch=17, col=4)
legend('bottomleft', legend=1:2, title='DVID', col=c(2, 4), pch=16:17)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(STUDYID = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
), ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TAD = c(0.5, 1, 
1.5, 1.5, 2.01667, 2.01667, 2.53333, 2.53333, 3, 3, 4, 4), DV = c(0.80871, 
2.53052, 2.6483, -0.94495, 2.74019, -0.69375, 2.91831, -0.30612, 
2.88926, -0.12863, 2.78932, 0.01882), DVID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), Index = c(" 2SUBJ10.5", "   2SUBJ11", " 2SUBJ11.5", 
"  2SUBJ11.5", "2SUBJ12.01667", "2SUBJ12.01667", "2SUBJ12.53333", 
"2SUBJ12.53333", "  2SUBJ13", "  2SUBJ13", " 2SUBJ14", " 2SUBJ14"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

@AndrewGB: Using a bigger hammer, I created a new column with a unique identifier ("Index" in original post).  I then used your code to remove the unmatched concentrations, and then used lag to look for the previous instance of the unique Index, since sample times, ID, TAD were all not unique through the entire data set. It generated NAs that I removed to yield a data.table that I could plot  It works, but the need to create the Index column is cludgy.  I figure there is a better way.

```
df$Index <- paste0(df$STUDYID, df$REGIMEN,"SUBJ", df$ID, df$TAD)
PairedData <- df  %>% 
group_by(STUDYID, REGIMEN, ID, TAD) %>%
filter(n() >1) 
PairedData.dt <- data.table(PairedData)
PairedData.dt [, lag := c(NA, DV[-.N]), by = Index]
PairedData.paired <- na.omit(PairedData.dt)
rename(PairedData.paired, c("Metabolite"="DV" , "Drug"="lag"))
```